# Using phpize without installing php-dev

Tags: server, apache2, php, sync

I am developing a PHP application that uses the [Sync](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.sync.php) extension.

On the development server, I installed Sync through PECL, with the command `sudo pecl install sync`. When I tried to bring the application to the production server, I did the same but encountered the error:

```
4 source files, building
running: phpize
sh: 1: phpize: not found
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

I found out that to use `phpize` I have to install the `php-dev` package on Ubuntu. On the development server I already had `php-dev`, but not on the production one.

Aside from the fact that it seems conceptually wrong to have something called "*dev*" on a production server, I don't want to install over 200 megabytes of packages for such a small purpose.

I was trying to think of alternative solutions, but I haven't found any that are simple and straightforward.

Maybe my approach is wrong? Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Your aporoach is wrong. If the development server's software environment is enhanced over thre production environment, one must be careful not to build in a dependency (`phpize`) that's unavailable in the production environment.

Comment: I ended up installing `php-dev` on the production server, even though it didn't make sense.